# I can't create a IP whitelist for port 3306

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-firewall

I'm working on a Windows Server and I want to protect users from connecting to port 3306 external. To achieve this, I want to create a whitelist in the firewall.

This is the tab with the selected port:
[image: port]

Also I have entered my IP in the Scope tab, to allow it. 
[image: ip]

Unfortuanatly, when I disable the full-allow rule, I can't access the MySQL databases anymore. What am I doing wrong?

[image: cmd]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not clear , but i will suppose that you want to limit the access to port 3306 on the server to only one client .

The connection is like following

ClientIP:RandomPort ----- >ServerIP:3306

You need to correct your rule configuration on the server:

1- Put the remote port configuration to any port(remote port of the client which is random)

2- Put the remote IP address th IP address of your client.